# Ключ сортировки

Tags: python-3.x, сортировка

Есть данные следующего вида:

```
[(1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (3,1), (3,2)]
```

какой ключ можно задать в sorted для сортировки, чтобы сортировка была следующим образом?

```
[(1,1), (2,1), (3,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,2), (1,3)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

вот так:

```
arr = [(3,2), (1,1), (1,2), (1,3), (2,1), (2,2), (3,1),]

res = sorted(arr, key=lambda obj: (obj[1], obj[0]))

print(res)
```

Я специально изменил исходный список иначе можно было бы применить

```
res = sorted(arr, key=lambda obj: obj[1])
```

а это вызывало бы в некоторых случаях ошибки сортировки

Comment: Да, все было и правда просто, спасибо)